# Using TableView to display PDF's in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I am using storyboard in xcode to desgin my app instead of xibs. This is my first time using them and i have a question. Right now I have multiple TableViews all with multiple cells inside. What i am trying to achieve is to click on the cell and that will then load a PDF. Each cell has a pdf that it should open. Instead of using segues and linking each tableview cell to its OWN view controller which would be very redundant. Is there some code i could put it a (I think UIWebView) that would let me see what cell was clicked and load the respective PDF. Is this possible? THank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the master detail view controller template for this, which will be easiest to set up, then you can disable the edit and the add buttons and set up your list of PDF's with an array.

Once they are all set up it will set the detail items automatically, if you don't have core data enabled you can access it by:
`[self.detailItem description];`

This gives you the name of the row that was clicked, which then you can use that to load the PDF to the UIWebView.  The web view can load the PDF to view with:

```
NSString *pdfName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.detailItem description]];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pdfName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[pdfViewer loadRequest:request];
[pdfViewer setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Just be sure to declare pdfViewer as your UIWebView in the detail view controller

Comment: is there anyway to do this for iphone, because i dont believe the iphone has the capability of using master detail view controller

Comment: iPhone does this the same way, it is just set up like the contacts app is, with the table view shown first and then the detail view when clicked